# splitted subquery and virtual table

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables Tag, Software and Software_Tag which make **many-to-many** relationship between two first.

I wish to split the subquery out on two parts (because i can not do in in one in mysql):

`(SELECT softwares_id FROM Software_Tag GROUP BY softwares_id HAVING COUNT(*) >=2) as my`

DELETE FROM Software_Tag WHERE tags_id=1 AND softwares_id IN (my)

Here i try use virtual table named 'my' to put it to second query.
How could i do it?

now it gets en exception like **check your sql server**.

--

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do it as:

```
DELETE FROM Software_Tag WHERE tags_id=1 AND softwares_id IN
(SELECT softwares_id FROM Software_Tag GROUP BY softwares_id HAVING COUNT(*) >=2)
```

This should work in MySQL.

Edit .. try this

```
DELETE ST1
FROM Software_Tag ST1 
JOIN (SELECT softwares_id FROM Software_Tag GROUP BY softwares_id HAVING COUNT(*) >=2) ST2 on ST1.softwares_id=ST2.softwares_id
where ST1.tags_id=1
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

Currently, you cannot delete from a table and select from the same table in a subquery.

Comment: yes. thxs. but fix software_id=softwares_id because i do not perditions yet.

Answer (score 1):

To use temporary tables, you need to do it like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_tmp;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE my_tmp SELECT softwares_id 
    FROM Software_Tag GROUP BY softwares_id 
    HAVING COUNT(*) >=2;
DELETE FROM Software_Tag 
    WHERE tags_id=1 
        AND softwares_id IN (SELECT softwares_id FROM my_tmp);
```

Comment: syntax error NEAR TEMPORARRY TABLE ... bla-bla - check mysql server version. i hava use 5.x from ubuntu 10.10 repositories. last one i guess.

Comment: I think it's because of `TEMPORARY` not `TEMPORARRY`

Comment: and the subquery was using `software_id` instead of `softwares_id`: `(SELECT softwares_id FROM my_tmp)`